# Change style with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this has been done before, but for some reason it won't work. I have a variable (width) in JS, and need that to reflect on CSS. So here's what I'm using `$('.top').css('width', bad);`, but for some reason it won't seem to work. I know that 
`$('.top').css('width', '50%');` works fine.

Here's all of my code

```
countMissing();

function countMissing() {

//Get total inputs
console.log("Total inputs " + form.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
//Divide by complete inputs out of 100% and get percent
console.log("The percentage is " + 100 / form.getElementsByTagName('input').length + "%");

//Check
var cback = function () {
    bad = 0;
    $('.form :text').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;


    });
    if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
    else $('.congrats').hide();
}
$(document).delegate('.form :text', 'focus', cback);
$(document).delegate('.form :text', 'keyup', cback);
$('.top').css('width',bad, '%');

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.top').css('width',bad, '%');
```

should be

```
$('.top').css('width', bad + '%');
```